# How to check intersection of two images that aren't rectangular?

Tags: ios, iphone

New user to the site, but I have used it in the past so I felt it best to ask my question here, for the best chance of getting a response.

What I'm dealing with is one object, this being the sprite for my latest app, which I need to check for when it comes in to contact with another object, in this case, a tunnel which will curve.

Now, I'm aware of CGRectIntersectsRect, however I can't see that being helpful, as if I've got 2 UIImages, that being the top and bottom of a "mountain", and said pieces curving, there's no doubt that the sprite would touch the "rectangle".

What I need is something to trigger when the sprite hits the actual wall, however my limited knowledge of Objective-C isn't helping my case.

I imagine someone out there will know what I can do to resolve this, as for all I know it could be a simple solution.

Thank you in advance everyone!

Comment: This is what we call a nontrivial problem. What graphics engine are you using? How are you drawing/animating them on screen? Are these sprites UIImages, or are you using OpenGL or one of it's wrappers like cocos2D?

Are your walls in a regular geometric shape that you could describe with line segments and/or curves? What about your sprites?

There is sample code that shows how to hit-test a point against a bitmap image, but if you have 2 bitmaps then it will be computationally expensive to figure out when they intersect.

Comment: In general, this is called collision detection.

Comment: Basically I've designed the sprites myself, have it displayed in a UIImageView, then have it animated through an NSArray. As for the the walls, they were originally going to be in the style of 8-bit, where it's obvious to see the pixels that form it.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd probably not build these basic pieces yourself. For iOS 7, you can use [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is built-in. If you want to support older versions of iOS, look at [cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org) (it's good for iOS 7, too).

But to the question, one approach for detecting arbitrary overlaps is to draw both objects into a buffer and check if there are any overlapping pixels (for instance, by drawing one in in pure red, and another in pure green, and then looking for pixels that have both). For a discussion of how to do this kind of thing in Core Graphics, see [Clipping a CGRect to a CGPath](http://robnapier.net/clipping-cgrect-cgpath/), which provides sample code for the simplest version (checking for the intersection of a rectangle and curve), but the same approach can be used more generally. Note that this drawing can get expensive if you're doing it constantly, so usually you first check whether the bounding rectangles overlap. That tells you whether it's even worth the trouble to look closer.

But first I'd look at SpriteKit.

Comment: Never had experience with SpriteKit personally, but I'll have a look in the near future.